# Create my own strlen and substring functions

Tags: c++, substr, strlen

I am trying to create my own strlen and substr functions and I have 1 problem.
for example, let say I have the string ABC, my strlen will return 3, let say I want to cut this string from 0 to 1 its should return to me A,but I get some trash values, if I insert the substr to a new char and check the length I will recieve 14.
this is my code:

```c
int len(char *w){
    int count=0;
    int i=0;
    while (w[i]!='\0')
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
    //cout<<"Length of word is:"<<count<<"\n";
    return count;

}

char *subs(char *w,int s,int e){
    int i,j;
    int size=0;size=(e-s);
    //cout<<"new size is:"<<size<<"\n";
    char *newW=new char[size];

    for(i=0,j=s;j<e;i++,j++)
    {
        newW[i]=w[j];  
    }

    return newW;

}

int main(){
    char* x="ABC";
    //int v=len(x);
    //cout<<v;
    char *n=subs(x,0,1);
    cout << len(n);
    for(int g=0;g<len(n);g++)
    //cout<<n[g];

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to get some comments what I did wrong, Thanks!

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: You need to put a `'\0'` on the end. And you need to make sure there is enough space for it too.

Comment: Ensure that you `delete[]` your char array after usage.

Comment: ... and you assign `*n = subs(x,0,1)` which assigns the first char of the return value to the uninitalizes char pointer n. Try reading something about c strings and memory management.

Comment: Thanks for giving answer its helped very much, there's only one thing to be understood here, the goal for asking question here is to know how to do. and probably that this is the last resort.for the down voters I am sorry that I didnt challenge you  enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition loop for `for(i = 0, j = s ; j < e && w[j] != '\0'; i++, j++)` and you need to allocate size +1 since you have to add a \0 at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

sub string should end with a '\0', the array size should add one. Here is the code:

```
char *subs(char *w,int s,int e){
    int i,j;
    int size=0;size=(e-s);
    //cout<<"new size is:"<<size<<"\n";
    char *newW=new char[size + 1];

    for(i=0,j=s;j<e;i++,j++)
    {
        newW[i]=w[j];  
    }
    newW[i] = '\0';

    return newW;
}
```