# Expression must have class type while using pointers

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I am trying to count in a string1 how many times string2 exists. For example:
string1 = abababd.
string2 = ab.
Result: 3.

(I must use pointers for this question)

What I have so far:

```
int mystr(char* s, char* t) {
    int counter = 0;
    int length = strlen(t);
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        char d[] = *s.substr(0, 2);
        if (*s == *t)
            counter++;
        *s += length;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I keep receiving the issue:
Expression must have class type for this line: char d[] = *s.substr(0, 2);
Can someone assist please?

Comment: `s` is a pointer to `char`, it does not have any `substr` methods, you are clearly mistaking it with `std::string`

Comment: also you cannot initialize an array like that

Comment: can substring overlap each other ? `"aba"` in `"abababd"`.

Comment: `auto d = std::string_view(s, length).substr(0, 2);`?

Comment: I am new to C++. how should I initialise it then?

Comment: @HenriMenke yeah like that is gonna teach the man to fish, not just eat a fish. :) It's HW!

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think I am in that level yet. What auto and string_view means?

Comment: @Mor this is a bit advanced for your level. Stick to the assignment for now, there is a really big chance that you get confused by these terms..

Answer (score 6):

[`substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) is a method of class [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).

You are using C pointers here (`char* s`), so there is no `substr()` to call, thus the error.

---

Of course, I'll leave the implementation to you, but you can get inspired by  [create my own substr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17596420/2411320).

---

Since OP is showing good faith in trying to do their own HW, let's comment on the approach so far:

```
int mystr(char* s, char* t) {
    int counter = 0;
    int length = strlen(t);
    // while we haven't reach the end of string
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        // this is not used anywhere, and it's wrong. Why 2? You want the length of `t` there, if you would use it anyway
        char d[] = *s.substr(0, 2);

        // this is wrong. It will increase the counter,
        // every time a character of the substring is matched with the
        // current character in the string
        if (*s == *t)
            counter++;

        // you want to read the next chunk of the string, seems good for a start
        *s += length;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

So now, you should focus on how to check if the current substring is matched in the string. So, you need to change this:

```
if (*s == *t)
    counter++;
```

into something that will check all the characters of `t`, versus the same number of characters of the string, from current position. So, you need to *iterate* through `*s`. How many times? *For* as much as the length of `t`.

In that iteration, you would need to check that the current character of string `s` is the *compared equal* to the current character of string `t`. When the iteration ends, and if all characters visited during that iteration where the same, then that means that you found a match! So, *if* that is true, then we should *increment* the counter.

---

<sub>Bonus: If you have time, and have completed the logic discussed above, think about `*s += length;` and this input: `s = "dabababd", t = "ab".</sub>

Comment: I tried adding the function and called it by:  int length2 = strlen(s);
 char newT[] = subs(s, 0, length2); it does an error again.

Comment: OK @Mor, try to debug it yourself. If you still have troubles, create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post *a new question*. I believe I answered your question, so you could accept my answer if you like. I really can give you the code and explain it to you, but I am pretty sure you will have much more gain by trying out yourself. So, try out, work hard on it, and if you are still in trouble, post a new question. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, thanks, but do you think my way of thinking is in the right direction?

Comment: @Mor that's the spirit! I updated my answer, I think it helps... Don't forget to accept the answer, if it answers your question. :)